# Rails 3 - Update_attribues won't get changed parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have somes relations in my table like this

```
Model : Floors
    has_many :photo

Model : Photo
     belongs_to :floors
     belongs_to :file_type

Model : file_type
     has_many :photo
```

Photo are nested attributes with render inside floors form.

The problem is if i change the file type inside the form without any other change in the form, the new selected alements are not updated, and the update_attributes (in the WEBrick) console, the new selected are not updated.

Photo are a paperclip element with versioning. I don't want to update each time the file if i just want to change his file type related.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : Has asked, my views.

```
# _form.html.erb
<% f.fields_for :floor_photo do |floor_photo| -%>
   <%= render 'floor_photo_fields', :f => floor_photo %>
<% end -%>
<div>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Photo", f, :floor_photo %>
</div>

# _floor_photo_fields.html.erb
<div class="fields">
  <%= f.label 'Photo' %><br/>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  <%= f.collection_select :file_type_id, FileType.all(:order => 'name'), :id, :name,   {:prompt => 'Select'}%>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %><br/>
  <div style="margin-bottom:10px;"><%= f.object.photo_file_name %></div>
</div>
```

For now, if i click Add Photo, and set a file type to the photo, it's work, but when i edit a floors and want to change the file type, he don't want to take the new file_type_id and don't do any update sql statement. Like if i have nothing changed in my form.

And yes, sorry for my relations, it was a typo mistake, all are good in my models form.

```
# floor_photo.rb
class FloorPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  versioned
  belongs_to :floor
  belongs_to :file_type

  has_attached_file :photo, :keep_old_files => true, :url => "/system/buildings/photos/:id/:version/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/buildings/photos/:id/:version/:basename.:extension"


  Paperclip.interpolates :version do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.version.to_s
  end
end


# file_type.rb
class FileType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :floor_photos
end
```

I hope this help someone to help me.

Sorry, here is my controller

```
floors_controllers.rb
def edit
@floor = Floor.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@floor = Floor.find(params[:id])
if @floor.update_attributes(params[:floor])
  redirect_to space_path(@floor)
else 
  render :action => 'edit'
end
end
```

Comment: You may want reformulate your question, because I don't understand what you are asking. Also please show the relevant view and controller code, so people can point out your mistakes.

Comment: Controller code too, please. Where are you using `update_attributes`?

Comment: ok, updated. But it's a normal update_attributes i think.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't look right:

```
Model : Floors
    has_many :photo #should be :photos

Model : Photo
     belongs_to :floors #should be :floor
     belongs_to :file_type

Model : file_type
     has_many :photo #should be :photos
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing change if i plurialize models.